# The UI Unity tab is missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

The UI tab is missing from the list of created objects. Here is a photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufZpb.jpg)

It's supposed to be between Video and Camera, but it's not there. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be old problem in unity
try to restart your **PC** or change **Layout**

Also check those Links if this not working

[Unity UI](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1100746/unity-5-tabs-disappear.html)

[UI Unity Problem](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-not-showing-when-i-right-click-on-hierarchy.732977/)